# Do custom script extensions specified in ARM templates run each time the VM is restarted?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

I used the sample template in the below link to create a VM with a custom script extension:

https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/201-vm-custom-script-windows

If I stop and start the VM from the azure portal then the custom script extension runs on startup.  But if I restart the VM from within the VM (by selecting Restart from the Start menu) the custom script extension does not run.  Why wouldn't the custom script extension run when the VM is restarted from within the VM?  Are custom script extensions only executed when a VM is started from a deallocated state?

When working with VM scale sets if I deallocate and then start a single VM in the scale set from the Azure portal the custom script extension for that VM does not execute.  But if I deallocate and then start the entire scale set from the Azure portal the custom script extension does execute for each VM.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Azure custom script extension allow the owner of the Azure VM to run script stored in Azure storage [**during or after VM provisioning**](https://github.com/Azure/azure-linux-extensions/pull/26/files). The script extension only executes once per VM, not every time the machine boots up - but if you stop the VM via Azure portal, and start the VM again, the VM will be re-provisioned, so the script will run again. Difference between the states of Azure Virtual machines stopped and stopped(deallocated), refer to the [link](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/gbanin/2015/04/22/difference-between-the-states-of-azure-virtual-machines-stopped-and-stopped-deallocated/).
If you need to run scripts repeatly, you can add a timestamp parameter to your custom script extension, more information refer to the [link](https://github.com/Azure/azure-linux-extensions/tree/master/CustomScript).

Comment: Thanks Jason!  This makes sense.  I do find the VM scale set behavior odd.  If I deallocate and then start a single VM in the scale set from the portal then the custom script extension does not run.  But if I deallocate and then start the entire scale set then the custom script extension runs.  I would think that the custom script extension should run when I deallocate and start a single VM in the scale set.

Comment: It seems that a timestamp parameter is only available in Azure Linux Extensions, as per the link provided. What about Windows VMs?

Comment: I don't think the "stop/start" part of this answer is correct. In Windows the extension state is stored in OS disk (C:\Packages), and if the extension was already executed once then it will not run again. Even if you deallocate and reallocate the machine (start/stop),  the information is still there in the managed disk, and the extension shouldn't run again.

Answer (score 0):

No. Once the VM is stopped (either deallocated or rebooted) and then Started the VM, custom script does not run each time.

**Custom script will be executed only on the fly - runs only for the first time during VM provisioning.**

Deallocating of VM and Starting the VM only matters about the change in the public ip address. However, dns naming would remain same.